# Computation within a column and averaging based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
player   school    team     result     exam
a        s1        z        False      English
a        s1        z        True       German
a        s1        z        True       Geography
b        s1        z        True       Geography
b        s1        z        True       History
b        s1        z        False      English
c        s1        y        False      English
d        s1        y        False      German
d        s1        y        True       English
d        s1        y        True       History
e        s1        w        True       German
e        s1        w        True       History
f        s1        w        False      English
```

The `school` is always the same. I want to compute the performance for every `player`, by the formula `(number of Trues) / (number of Trues + number of Falses)`. But then I want to see the average per team. I would imagine something like (I hope I didn't make any computation error):

```
school    team    TeamResult
s1        z       0.67
s1        y       0.67
s1        w       0.50
```

Does anyone know how I could "go back" to the team the users are from? What I tried so far was extremely inefficient, namely creating new dataframes from the "big" one for each team, like `df_new = df[df['team'] == 'z']`. Is there any other more direct way?

Comment: I think your 0.83 should be 0.67 (e.g., for team z -> 4/6 = 0.67)

Comment: @mozway thank you! I think for team y too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `groupby`+`mean`:

```
df.groupby(['school', 'team'])['result'].mean()
```

To match the exact specified output:

```
(df.groupby(['school', 'team'])
   ['result'].mean()
   .rename('TeamResult')
   .sort_values(ascending=False)  
   .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
  school team  TeamResult
0     s1    w    0.666667
1     s1    z    0.666667
2     s1    y    0.500000
```

Comment: Why not just use mean?

Comment: @sammywemmy very true :D

Comment: Sometimes the brain does inexplicable things ;)

Comment: This makes sense to me, but I get an error on the second row saying there are no numeric types to aggregate.

Comment: Make sure your True/False are booleans